# Firebase cloud functions 'Logging is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

FYI I'm not a native Node.js dev

I unexpectedly kept getting a `500 service error` that came out of no where, occurred for several hours, then everything started to work just again without any effort on my end. After googling around I couldn't find much info about the error but I did find info that said to report it. I came across this [doc to report errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/reporting-errors).

In my code below when an error is caught in the `catch`, I use the code from the docs to report it but when I run my `index.js` file I keep getting the error:

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> TypeError: Logging is not a function

Error Code:

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Logging is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lance/Cloud_Functions/functions/index.js:12:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
```

I checked inside my `package.json` file and the `"@google-cloud/logging": "^8.1.1"` library is there.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^8.1.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**Where am I going wrong?**

Index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const Logging = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const logging = Logging();

exports.runTest = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    return refOne.update({ "...": "..."})
    .then(() => { 
        return refTwo.set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
                    
        return reportError(error);
    });
});

function reportError(err, context = {}) {
  // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that will receive the log
  // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but must contain "err"
  // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error Reporting.
  const logName = 'errors';
  const log = logging.log(logName);

  // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
  const metadata = {
    resource: {
      type: 'cloud_function',
      labels: { function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME },
    },
  };

  // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
  const errorEvent = {
    message: err.stack,
    serviceContext: {
      service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
      resourceType: 'cloud_function',
    },
    context: context,
  };

  // Write the error log entry
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Ok, I’ll change it in a few.  But what’s the matter with screen shots?

Comment: They can't be found though search, nor copy/pasted into answers. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20can't%20be%20searched,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.

Comment: oh, the makes a lot of sense, thanks for the advice. I updated the question with the actual code

Comment: See the documentation for usage: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) you need to import `Logging` with brackets around it (necessary when the required package doesn't have a default export):

`const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');`

then instantiate logging with:

`const logging = new Logging({projectId}); // You're currently missing the projectId argument`

Comment: I saw that under the comments in the link that @DougStevenson posted. I’ll upvote your answer to give you some extra points though . Thanks!

Comment: Haha thanks, I'm new here! Best of luck with your project.    